# Methods for finding the $\int_{\vert z\vert=1} {1 \over z^2} tan({\pi \over z}) dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

Find the value of the $\int_{\vert z\vert=1} {1 \over z^2} tan({\pi \over z}) dz$

When we substitute $\omega = {1 \over z}$, Then we would get the $\int_{\vert \omega \vert=1}  tan({\omega \pi}) d\omega = 4i$.

I tried the different way by using the statement I've believed it always holds.

-statement-

$\int_{\vert z\vert=r} f(z) dz = 2\pi i \bullet res(z^2f({1 \over z}), 0)$

So the case given above, $f(z)  =  {1 \over z^2} tan({\pi \over z})$. Hence, $z^2f({1 \over z}) = tan(z\pi)$

The answer is $2\pi i \bullet res(tan(z\pi), 0) =0$

I can't understand why does the $0$ is not answer. Is the statement  false?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are many more poles than just the $z=0$.  Also you made a sign error in the $w=1/z$ case since $dw=-z^{-2}dz$ and you also reverse orientation of the circle contour.

Comment: There actually isn't a pole at $z=0$ at all because it is not an isolated singularity.

Comment: @user10354138, Ah yes I revised the sign error.